# SQLiteDatabase syntax error (code 1) near create table while compiling

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm creating a simple budget managing app. To store budget details I've created a table.here's my DataBaseHelper class :

```
package com.example.rajkumar.budget;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME="SQLiteDatabase.db",
   TABLE_NAME="MyBudget";
   public static final String COLUMN_FIRST_NAME="NAME", 
   COLUMN_TWO_NAME="BUDGET_NAME",
   COLUMN_THREE_NAME="LIMIT";
   public DataBaseHelper(Context context){
   super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + "VARCHAR," + COLUMN_TWO_NAME
            + "VARCHAR," + COLUMN_THREE_NAME + "DECIMAL);");
}
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
 public boolean addBudget(String name,String bname,String bLimit){
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_FIRST_NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_TWO_NAME,bname);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_THREE_NAME, bLimit);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
    return true;
}
public Cursor getDetails(){
    SQLiteDatabase db= getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select *from MyBudget;",null);
    return c;
}
}
```

below is a class from where values are provided to create table.

```
package com.example.rajkumar.budget;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BudgetDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editName,editBname,editLimit;
Button btnCreate;
private TextView budgetName,name,limit;
private DatabaseHelper db;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.enter_budget);
    editName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editBname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editLimit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    btnCreate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
    btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            insert();
        }
    });
    setContentView(R.layout.budget_details);
    budgetName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewbname);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewname);
    limit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewlimit);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    showDetails();
    Button btndel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btndel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(BudgetDetails.this, "Delete later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
private void insert(){
    String name=editName.getText().toString().trim();
    String bname=editBname.getText().toString().trim();
    String blimit=editLimit.getText().toString().trim();
    db.addBudget(name,bname,blimit);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Budget Created Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


private void showDetails(){
        Cursor c=db.getDetails();
        c.moveToFirst();
        budgetName.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME)));
        name.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TWO_NAME)));
        limit.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_THREE_NAME)));
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.home:
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            return(true);
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            return(true);
        case R.id.settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return(true);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

the main activity consists of a grid view where i want to click an item and open a layout to enter budget details and save it in a table and dispaly the details in a separate layout. the app runs well until i click on an item and then it displays "Unfortunately (myapp) has stopped". below is my MainActivity code

```
package com.example.rajkumar.budget;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
GridView grid;String[] budget=        {"Quick","Budget","Expenses","Reports","Tips","About"};
int[] ImageId=  {R.drawable.bookmark,R.drawable.bookshelf,R.drawable.briefcase,R.drawable.candy,
R.drawable.car,R.drawable.clock};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CustomGrid adapter=new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this,budget,ImageId);
    grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,BudgetDetails.class);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            i.putExtra("id",position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.home:
            return(true);
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            return(true);
        case R.id.settings:
            Toast.makeText(this,"Settings Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return(true);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

here's the logcat error messages :

```
11-30 05:26:06.469  1605-1605/com.example.rajkumar.budget W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:                             nable to resolve virtual method 369:     Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity       (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
11-30 05:26:06.469    1605-1605/com.example.rajkumar.budget D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:    replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-30 05:26:06.639    1605-1605/com.example.rajkumar.budget E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "TABLEMyBudget": syntax error
11-30 05:26:06.639    1605-1605/com.example.rajkumar.budget D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-30 05:26:06.679    1605-1605/com.example.rajkumar.budget W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0c70b20)
11-30 05:26:06.679    1605-1605/com.example.rajkumar.budget E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rajkumar.budget, PID: 1605
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.example.rajkumar.budget/com.example.rajkumar.budget.BudgetDetails}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEMyBudget": syntax    error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEMyBudget(NAMEVARCHAR,BUDGET_NAMEVARCHAR,LIMITDECIMAL);
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: I just don't know where the error is..

Comment: The issue is like, you are not giving any space between column name and type also tablename.

Comment: @Raj do one thing , download a sqlite tool or chrome  extension , create a table in that tool using UI , and the get create query copy paste this query. SqlLiteBrowser is a good one.

Comment: You should read the traces/logs carefully. You could have easily got the error.

Comment: Please learn to read the logcat: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEMyBudget": syntax    error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEMyBudget(NAMEVARCHAR,BUDGET_NAMEVARCHAR,LIMITDECIMAL);`

Comment: ok thanks guys, I'm novice that y. I'll learn.

Comment: @Nouman ,thanks for suggesting. I'll do that

Comment: it worked but another similar error,

Comment: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "LIMIT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE MyBudget (NAME VARCHAR,BUDGET_NAME VARCHAR,LIMIT NUMBER);

Comment: This is **another** question. Anyway, you can't use the word `LIMIT` because it's a reserved keyword. Better use something like `Budget_Limit`.

Answer (score 5):

Put a space before and after your variables in your `CREATE` statement:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + " VARCHAR," + COLUMN_TWO_NAME
            + " VARCHAR," + COLUMN_THREE_NAME + " DECIMAL);")
```

You'll also have to adjust your other queries in the same way (the `DROP` query for example)